# Check that one of strings in array exist in another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$darkoobtitle = $_POST['darkoobtitle'];
    $forbiddens = array("value4", "value5", "value3","value2","value1");
    $checkforbidden = explode(" ",$darkoobtitle);
    foreach ( $forbiddens as $forbidden ) 
{
if(in_array($forbidden,$checkforbidden)) exit();
}
```

I would like to find out if there in a function in PHP 8 to check if $forbiddens exist in $darkoobtitle.

I search for a function in PHP to do that in a right way

Comment: Did you try array_intersect() ?